# Process Monitor (procmon) does not show some UDP / TCP network activity events, shown in Network Monitor

Tags: windows, networking, procmon, tracing, netmon

I observe sometimes a difference between Process Monitor and [Network Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Network_Monitor). Process Monitor does not show some UDP / TCP network events.

Here is an example:

> net use * \\test12345.domain.local\test

shows in Netmon as:

[image]

shows in Process Monitor:

[image]

Why is the [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) nameservice (:137) communication is missing in Process Monitor?

(I've tested it on several virtual and physical Windows PCs, like Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008.)

Comment: I would ask on the sysinternals forum and for more clues, there is a fork of Wireshark that associates packets with process, if netmon doesn't.  It might be that the 137 network traffic happens at the kernel level from a Localsystem level access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System is deactivated by the default filter (exclude system events). Delete the filter and these events will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark: Use psexec to run Process Monitor as localsystem.

Comment: What is *"localsystem"*? A Windows user account? Or something else? Can you add a reference?